# is there an equivalent of Python's multiprocessing module for Rust

Tags: multithreading, rust, concurrency, multiprocessing, thread-safety

In python there's a multiprocessing module where you can run a function inside a child process,
I know what you're thinking, but Rust doesn't have Gil, wouldn't threads do the same thing for you?

No, because I have tasks that connect to different databases at the same time using different odbc drivers, a lot of the odbc drivers are not thread safe,
(I don't know if it's thread safety but if I run 2 different drivers at the same time in different threads, that doesn't work for some reason)

please don't focus on the ODBC drivers part, it's a long story and it's specific to ODBC, I'm sure others might need to run Rust functions in a process instead of threads for various reasons, most of them won't be valid but some of them would and that's a bit besides the point of this question

so I need to run each parallels task in separate memory scope, aka a process.

I don't mind the complexity involving passing values and variable between processes and child\parent process, I think I know how to do that (at least how to do it using Redis)

in python this is done using this:

```
from multiprocessing import Process

    def f(name):
        print('hello', name)
    
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        p = Process(target=f, args=('bob',))
        p.start()
        p.join()
```

notice how the parameter "target" in "Process" takes a function.

I know Rust have Process too but it doesn't take a Rust function to run in a separate process, it takes a binary, that might work but it's harder to develop, I have to compile a separate rust project as a binary for this to work, while if it can just run a function\closure in a child process, then it could be one project

what I'm looking for is something like this, but instead of "tokio" imagine it's "process" (so process::spawn)

```
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> io::Result<()> {
        // replace tokio::spawn with process::spawn
        tokio::spawn(async move {
            dostuff.await
        });
}
```

Comment: You can just spawn additional processes with [`Command`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/struct.Command.html) and use your favorite IPC. But none of what you've described really needs a different process, threads will work fine for your case. "Not thread safe" doesn't mean you can't use it in threads after all everything runs in one, the main thread, it means you can't use it in **different threads at the same time**.

Comment: but I do need to use them in different threads at the same time,
i have like 80 databases with different types (postgres, mysql etc) that i need to make sure they're are up,
i send 80 concurrent  health check queries to them, I need do that work in a separate tasks at the same time

Comment: Yes that's possible, you just can't use **the same database connection** in multiple threads at the same time or move the connection between threads. That doesn't change by using processes instead. For example one thread per database will work just fine for your usecase.

Comment: Command, doesn't copy the current code context,
I think it's meant for if you want to use say "ls" or "dir" from Rust, but there should be a way to run a rust code block inside a child process, maybe?

Comment: "you just can't use the same database connection"
i'm fine with that, they are not the same databases anyways connection pooling only works if you are connecting to the same database

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#contexts-and-start-methods
this what I mean by context, notice that python is running python code from the caller and coping its resources (variables), not a separate binary like ping, ls, dir etc

Comment: Using things which are not thread safe **within** a thread is totally fine see this [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=2f0e52ec10818d4386e20caba423f67d) Unless you have some secret requirements I'm 100% certain you just want to use threads.

Comment: Thanks for your replies and the playground, I guess my worry is the ODBC drivers are not native to Rust they are called by Rust using the ODBC, the only way it worked for me in Python was using multiprocessing, but in Rust it might just work with threads, the only difference between Rust and Python in terms of Threads is GIL, they both will call the same ODBC driver manager, but there might be other things at play, at this point I will just port my code from python to Rust using threads, and see where that takes me,

Thank you

Comment: This is literally the reason that `Send` and `Sync` exist: to prevent you from sending and sharing something non-thread-safe between threads. They allow you to write multi-threaded code that interacts with non-thread-safe, single-threaded code.

Comment: The real question isn't whether your drivers are thread-safe, but whether they are _reentrant_. If they're not reentrant, you will indeed need to use processes. Note that `fork` does copy the caller state, but you need some kind of IPC to send back the results since `fork` uses copy-on-write and therefore the caller won't see the modifications made by the callee (which is the whole point of using processes rather than threads).

Comment: "Note that fork does copy the caller state"
do you have a quick example of that?
I looked up the fork document and it takes a command and binary as argument,

what I'm looking for is something like thead::spawn or  tokio::spawn but for processes

Comment: IME, I've seen lots of binary-only libraries out there that use a private hidden global variable as the `handle` for the whatever connection they are handling, and if you try to use a single program to drive more than one connection at the same time, they won't work.

Comment: About the `fork`, the good old POSIX [fork](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) takes no arguments whatsoever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a matter of fact, there is: the crate [`mitosis`](https://crates.io/crates/mitosis) offers a primitive analogous to `thread::spawn`, which spawns a subprocess instead a thread.  However, the mechanism by which it does so is pretty sketchy, [full of loopholes, shaky assumptions and introducing a number of security weaknesses](https://github.com/Manishearth/mitosis/issues/13).  You should consider it a proof-of-concept experiment more than a practical implementation.

The vast majority of the time, you don’t need to have a separate process.  Any issues with non-thread-safety and non-reentrancy should be possible to mitigate by not accessing any problematic objects outside a single dedicated thread, and using thread-safe primitives to have it intermediate between your threaded code and non-thread-safe code.